# Calendar sidebar in Outlook for Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook

I'm using Outlook for Mac 15.33 and sometimes check Outlook on a different machine that has Windows. The Windows version's default setup has a sidebar on the right, essentially a summary of the calendar. How do I enable that feature on the Outlook for Mac version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is called the "To-Do Bar" or sometimes referred to as the task bar. It's currently not a feature of Outlook for Mac, but is available in most currently used versions of Outlook for Windows.

Sources:

- [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macofficeo365-macoutlook/display-to-do-list-in-outlook-2016-for-mac/64d8a12d-6cef-4373-ade1-5a6317822113?auth=1)
- [Outlook feedback](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293343-outlook-for-mac/suggestions/9114511-to-do-bar-have-calendar-and-task-pane-in-mail-vie)